# Why NFS Client is introduced?

Tags: java, nfs

I have NFS server where in i require to host files and read it. The approach to read and write file on NFS server found is

> using [NFS Client Like here](https://github.com/EMCECS/nfs-client-java).

My question is when we can write content on NFS server with normal java read/write program then why is NFS client introduced ? Is there any service specific to NFS which these client provide and why is it different than normal file creation process ?

Comment: By read/write program, you mean file io api?

Comment: @zaerymoghaddam Yes File Operations

Answer (score 1):

When you're using normal Java API to access a NFS folder, all communications are actually handled by your OS. So you can just use the normal File API and Java doesn't know if it's accessing a local file or a remote one. But in cases that your OS doesn't support NFS (e.g. if your Java app is running in an environment with limited resources or NFS mounting is disabled in OS level) or you are developing an application that needs more lower level details about the NFS resource (e.g. when you're developing a framework or a middleware), you may need to be able to communicate directly with the server that is exposing files/folders via a library like *nfs-client-java*.